Code inside subscription of Http observable is not executed
We have an Angular 16.x.x based FE application where when we have an Observable for http request for orders checkout.component. We have placed a toastr inside .next() of the subscription along with a logger and the reason why we have placed the logger is to ensure the success response which we realized for some reasons that sometimes it does not execute the code inside .next(), however the order is placed and success response is ensured from the backend.
Checkout Component
    this.accountService
      .checkout(orderObj)
      .pipe(finalize(() => (this.loading = false)))
      .subscribe({
        next: (res: any) => {
          logdna.log(`Checkout successful for: ${orderObj.email}`);
          this.toastr.success('Your order has been placed successfully');
        }
      });

Account Service
    checkout(checkoutDetails: any) {
        return this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/checkout`, {
           requestObjectPayload //object here, different in real
        });
    }

What could be the possible reason? It is the first time i am facing such an issue and i have no clue why is it even happening?

Depending on the method you are using the observable completes. So you need to implement the complete part.

Complete part as in?

this.accountService
.checkout(orderObj)
.pipe(finalize(() => (this.loading = false)))
.subscribe({
complete: () => {
logdna.log(Checkout successful for: ${orderObj.email});
this.toastr.success('Your order has been placed successfully');
}
});

And how'd i get the response object inside complete() handler?

Same way as for the others ... just left it out because you did not use it.

@ThomasRenger the .complete handler do not accept any param and to get the response object .next() is the only option. In order to further process the response object, i have to write logic inside .next().

My bad, thought i was talking about subscribe(result => ....), sorry for the confusion. I always handle everything in the pipe part not in the subscription part, because it is compatible to signals or the asnyc pipe approach.

I could only possibly guess that the backend sends an HTTP error despite processing the request. Try to log the error block in the subscribe: .subscribe({ next: (res: any) => { ... }, error: (error: any) => logdna.log('Checkout failed:', ${error}) });

if requestObject is an object should be (without { }):
return this.http.post(${environment.apiURL}, requestObjectPayLoad)

NOTE: You can add the "error" part
   this.accountService
      .checkout(orderObj)
      .pipe(finalize(() => this.loading = false))
      .subscribe({
        next: (res: any) => {
          logdna.log(`Checkout successful for: ${orderObj.email}`);
          this.toastr.success('Your order has been placed successfully');
        },
        //add the error part
        error:((res:any)=>{ 
             console.log("error", res)
        } 
      });


The code works absolutely fine, the object i added is an example payload which is working fine and brackets are fine as well in the real code. Also we do have the error() part where we have the logs as well where nothing is being logged as the response is success. The issue is that at time on success response, it does not execute the code inside .next().
